# Is there any swift package for video filter for ios app?

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, video-capture

Am new to IOS swift. I want to make camera filters for both live preview and saving video. Is there any package in swift?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Google is your friend.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes there are multiple by I've used [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) and it works perfectly fine with swift. You can find implementation details [here](https://swiftpackageregistry.com/BradLarson/GPUImage2)

Comment: This is suitable as a comment, not an answer. Please review [answer].